# Which are the options for PostgreSQL connection pooling in Windows?

Tags: django, windows, postgresql, connection-pooling

I want to start using connection pooling with a PgSQL database. The restriction is that, sadly, I must use Windows in the server. [pgpool](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page), which have been my favorite for this, does not support Windows.

I've read about [pgbouncer](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pgbouncer), but I've never tried it. Another option is to use a pool in the application layer. It's a Django based app so I could use [django-db-pool](https://github.com/gmcguire/django-db-pool).

Are there any other options?

Which one do you think is better?

Comment: pgbouncer is simple and capable and production ready.

Comment: The only thing that holds me back of installing pgbouncer in production is that I can't find any official release for Windows. Instead, the pgbouncer team offers external links to experimental builds. Anyway, I'm going to give it a try in staging.

Answer (score 1):

In-app connection pooling is usually preferable when it's available and known to work well. The only time I'd make an exception to that is when many different apps or appservers were using the same DB; then I'd want an external pooler.

For pooling options see:

- [Pg wiki: connection pooling](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling#Connection_Pooling_and_Acceleration)
- [Pg wiki: number of database connections](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections)

Comment: This server is used exclusively by the django app. Then it would make sense to use django-db-pool. I will try with both options and choose the one which performs better.